# Xcode 8.3.2 Crashing while starting

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have updated Xcode by downloading the Xcode 8.3.2.xip file. Xcode is behaving weirdly after upgration.

I am using Sierra OS with Xcode 8.3.2 and the following error dialog pops when ever i try to open Xcode.

I have been trying to solve it for hours now, by trying to un-install Xcode completely and by removing the Xcode directories inside Library, etc. But nothing have worked so far.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]